# Blossom algorithm library implementation? Maximum matching in a general graph

Tags: graph, matching

Is there any well-tested and documented implementation? (preferrably in Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NeworkX -  max_weight_matching](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html?highlight=blossom)