# Why is the blossom algorithm more well used than the Micali-Vazirani algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

To by understanding, the Micali-Vazirani algorithm (1980) is *significantly* better in time complexity than the blossom algorithm (1961) (Micali-Vazirani is [O(V^{1/2} E)](https://doi.org/10.1109%2FSFCS.1980.12) and blossom is  [O(V^2 E)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) for maximum cardinality matching in general graphs. Yet, the blossom seems to be much more widely used, even recently ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297113)). Even packages desinged to solve these problems implement blossom over Micali-Vazirani ([1](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html?highlight=max_weight_matching#networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching)). Why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica in time complexity. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I see.... that's actually a really interesting question, then. I'm going to follow the question I think b/c I'd like to know the answer to this too.

Comment: Beware that the ease of implementation is essential in practice. So, the time complexity is not enough all the time. It's a pain and gain between pragmatism and performance. When the weight of performance gets higher, you can see the other implementation.

Comment: Has anyone worked out the details of Micali-Vazirani for general *weighted* matching? M-V might not be faster than Blossom as the primal algorithm in the primal-dual framework, and my unscientific sense is that weighted general matching is a more common problem than unweighted.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Micali-Vazirani algorithm seems to just be optimizing the shrinking of blossoms. I don't believe that this is restricted to unweighted matching, although I could be wrong. Would you mind pointing out where you see this in literature?

Comment: @user760900 I'm sure it works as a weighted subroutine, the question is whether it improves the running time (for example, in the bipartite case, the Hungarian algorithm runs faster than running Hopcroft--Karp |V| times).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Micali-Vazirani does not support weights, the routine you linked from `networkx` is for finding a maximum *weight* matching. If your graph is bipartite and you don't need weights, people also resort to the much simpler Hopcroft-Karp which matches Micali-Vazirani's bound, also hampering its popularity. It's the complexity of implementing Micali-Vazirani that is the main hurdle, I believe.

The fully unconditional state of the art for maximum *weight* matching is not that much better than Edmonds O(mn<sup>2</sup>), there is the 1990 algorithm from [*Data structures for weighted matching and nearest common ancestors with linking*](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Epettie/matching/Gabow-maximum-matching-LCA-with-linking.pdf) by HN Gabow that solves it in O(mn + n<sup>2</sup> log n). But at this small of a speedup the simplicity of the implementation of the algorithm and constant factors rule.

If you are okay with approximations there is an interesting complexity found in the 2014 paper [*Linear-Time Approximation for Maximum Weight Matching*](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Epettie/papers/ApproxMWM-JACM.pdf) by Ran Duan and Seth Pettie (also containing a nice survey of algorithms), which can solve the problem in O(m/ɛ log(1/ɛ)) time for an (1-ɛ)-approximation. That is, if you are okay with the weight of your matching being, say, 10% off the maximum weight matching you get O(m) complexity.

Comment: I presume the results achieved by [Blum (1990)](http://cedric.cnam.fr/~bentzc/INITREC/Files/MC3.pdf), by [Gabow and Tarjan (1990)](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/matching/Gabow-Tarjan-scaling-general-graph-matching.pdf), and by [Mucha and Sankowski(2006)](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~mucha/pub/mucha_sankowski_focs04.pdf) have similar problems?

Comment: Blum (1990) is unweighted, Gabow and Tarjan (1990) which I accidentally looked over is state of the art for integer weights (much better asymptotically than Gabow (1990)) but looks really complicated and not applicable to non-integer weights. That algorithm has been improved [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1919.pdf) even further. If you can implement it and you are okay with integer weights it is state of the art, but be prepared. Mucha and Sankowski is purely theoretical, since efficient (where ω <= 2.5) matrix multiplication is a galactic algorithm to our current knowledge.

Comment: Doing some further reading, it appears Mucha and Sankowski (2006) is currently good for a few applications, but in practice is worse for most applications.